# Updating to Rails 5 schema issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Recently I have been attempting to update an existing Ruby on Rails application from Rails version 4.2.7.1 to version 5.0.6.
After spending a fair amount of time resolving issues I attempted to run `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` however I am met with several problems related to my 'schema.rb'.

My problems seem to be coming from a specific table in my schema.

Rails 4.2.7.1 version:

```
create_table "coaches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "desired_hours"
end
```

Rails 5.0.6 version:

```
create_table "coaches", id: :integer, default: -> { "nextval('coaches_id_seq1'::regclass)" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "desired_hours"
  end
```

I seem to be encountering a number of issues due to this `nextval('coaches_id_seq1'::regclass)` addition to the schema table.

When I run `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` I am met with a warning `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "coaches_id_seq1" does not exist`

I have attempted to remove this line (`nextval('coaches_id_seq1'::regclass)`) from the table. However this lead to a number of errors:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
       DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 92, 2010-09-01 07:00:25.133275, 2010-09-01 07:00:25.133275, null).
       : INSERT INTO "coaches" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"`

I have also tried using `bundle exec rake db:structure:load` however this has resulted in even more errors.

Any help regarding this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks!

UPDATE

After a second attempt I discovered that running `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, is what triggers the change in the schema.rb. Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How/why did `nextval('coaches_id_seq1'::regclass)` get added to your schema? You've shown the "before and after" schemas, but not explained what caused the change.

Comment: The only relevant thing I see in the rails upgrade guide is [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#foreign-key-support), which is in reference to a Rails 4.1 --> 4.2 upgrade; which is not what your question is apparently in relation to?

Comment: ... Or perhaps this is in reference to [section 3.20.6](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#new-framework-defaults)??

Comment: I'm unsure why this change was made. It was an automated change that occurred during the Rails version update.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know the reproduction steps? You can't remember what tools you used / commands you ran / guide you followed? What happens if you just revert to the "old" schema?

Comment: I had an issue updating my database to rails 5.1. What solved it was stating the rails version in my migration. Don't know if that will solve your issue but its worth a try. I defined it like so `class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]`

Comment: I attempted this update for the second time and have discovered that the schema.rb is altered when running `bundle exec rails db:migrate`.

This is what triggers the change from:
`create_table "coaches", force: :cascade do |t|`
to:
`create_table "coaches", id: :integer, default: -> { "nextval('coaches_id_seq1'::regclass)" }, force: :cascade do |t|`

If anyone has any idea why this is happening please let me know.